# Why .btn-primary class is being applied even though not used at all?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am really confused as to why .btn-primary class is being used here and why not .btn-outline-* is shown properly with the correct background color (it has bluish background which should not have).
here is the code

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

function Skills() {
  return (
    <section id="section3">
      <div className="item1">
        <h1>Work In progress!</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="item2">
        <Button className="btn btn-outline-dark">HI</Button>
      </div>
      <div className="item3"></div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Skills;
```

as you can see .btn-primary is there
[image: as you can see .btn-primary is there]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Button component from react has a default variant of `primary`. Even though you don't specify it here it automaticaly assumes it. That's why you're getting the `btn-primary` class. Instead of using classes just use variant

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

function Skills() {
  return (
    <section id="section3">
      <div className="item1">
        <h1>Work In progress!</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="item2">
        <Button variant="btn-outline-dark">HI</Button>
      </div>
      <div className="item3"></div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Skills;
```